# Logstash doesn't parse logs if i don't define start_position

Tags: logstash

Below is my code. When I try to run this pipeline. Pipeline is starting but not parsing the logs. I have deleted .sincedb files at (data/plugins/inputs/file).

```
input {
    file {
        path => ".../directory/*.log"
    }
}
filter {
    
}
output { 
    stdout{
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

But if I put,

```
start_position => "beginning"
```

That works. But everytime it starts from beginning, not where it left. If i put the below code and delete .sincedb files. It still doesn't parse.

```
start_position => "end"
```

In the first case that i didn't define start_position or define start_position => "end". That waits at "Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}" But both cases I deleted .sincedb files. How can i make logstash continue where it left ?
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in documentaion for file input plugin, **start_position** is only considered the first time a file is read.

So it should work. With start_position => "beginning" it should start from the beggining the first time and continue from the last position written in .sincedb file.

> This option only modifies "first contact" situations where a file is
> new and not seen before, i.e. files that don’t have a current position
> recorded in a sincedb file read by Logstash. If a file has already
> been seen before, this option has no effect and the position recorded
> in the sincedb file will be used.

Make sure that logstash has write perimissions to the data directory.
Also try reducing the sincedb_write_interval.

Finally, as described in documentation, sincedb records can expire.
If you try to read many files, it may be preferable to use filebeat for reading the logs and passing them to logstash instead of using logstash's file input plugin with sincedb.

> Sincedb records can now be expired meaning that read positions of
> older files will not be remembered after a certain time period. File
> systems may need to reuse inodes for new content. Ideally, we would
> not use the read position of old content, but we have no reliable way
> to detect that inode reuse has occurred. This is more relevant to Read
> mode where a great many files are tracked in the sincedb. Bear in mind
> though, if a record has expired, a previously seen file will be read
> again

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for answering. If you like the question feel free to upvote :)